# Comparability of modulus of complex valued function.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex valued function.
I want to show that
$$ \|f\|_{L^2} \simeq MN$$
for some real constant $M,N$ and where $A\simeq B$ (say $A$ and $B$ are comparble) means that there are some constants $c$ and $C$ such that
$$ cB \le A \le CB.$$

If I obtain $\|f\|_{L^2}<MC$ for some $C$, can first equality be deduced from this?

Comment: Could you please give me the definition of $||f||$ and $L$? What is the complex number $z = f(x_1,...,x_n)$ ?

Comment: It is standard $L^2$ norm, i.e. $\|f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|^2 dx$.